# C# - Split string into an array of string using RegEx and create a dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, regex

How can i create a RegEx that will split a string format just like below into an array of string?
The string should have key and value seperated with semicolon, if there is no ',' that seperate the key-value, it should not have pass the test RegEx.

The string will look like this:

```
var splitMe = "[Key1,Value1][Key2,Value2][Key3,Value3][Key4,Value4]";
var splitedArray = Regex.Split(/'RegEx Here'/);

//Output value should like this one ["Key1,Value1","Key2,Value2","Key3,Value3","Key4,Value4"]
//this value also will be the key and value of a Dictionary<string,string>
```

Comment: Is it possible for a key or value to have any of the following characters: `[],;`? If so, then this text is not considered "regular" for purposes of regular expressions. While it might be possible to accomplish this with regex, it's probably not the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to use `Regex.Matches` chained with Linq to get the dictionary directly :

```
var input = "[Key1,Value1][Key2,Value2][Key3,Value3][Key4,Value4]";

var dictionary = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[(?<key>\w+),(?<value>\w+)\]")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, x => x.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you, I would imagine:

```
\[(\w+,\w+)\]
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sI4lK0/1)

I'm not sure what data you might have in keys and values but perhaps the following would be more inclusive?

```
\[([^,]+?,[^,]+?)\]
```

If you want to use split still you can match what you need with this:

```
(\[|\]\[|\])
```

Comment: I test your solution but the output of array is like this one: `["","Key1,Value1","","Key2,Value2","","Key3,Value3","","Key4,Value4"]`.,.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad dont use split, use match and just capture the matches.